# 彼がいる場所、彼がいるその場所、彼がいる学校

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

I am trying to understand what makes a 文節 内の関係 or 外の関係. And if 外の関係, which one.

> 彼がいる場所
> 彼女と初めて会ったところ

Am I correct in thinking these two can only be 外の関係の内容補充修飾節, because I can't put the 被修飾名詞 back with a 格助詞?

> *彼が場所にいる
> *ところで彼女と初めて会った

What about these?

> 彼がいるその場所
> 彼女と初めて会ったそのところ

These are 内の関係, aren't they?

> 彼がその場所にいる
> そのところで彼女と初めて会った

Despite lack of 指示語, these seem to be 内 instead of 外:

> 彼がいる学校
> 彼女と初めて会ったパーティー

> 彼が学校にいる
> パーティーで彼女と初めて会った

Why is that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 外の関係 and 内の関係. Do you know an introductory article about them?

Comment: @naruto I first learned those terms from aguijonazo's comments yesterday under another question of mine. Here's a page I found on this: https://yousei.arc-academy.net/manbow/index.php/term/detail/1387 and a pdf https://www.anlp.jp/proceedings/annual_meeting/2017/pdf_dir/P2-2.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all 内の関係.

彼がいる場所 and 彼女と初めて会ったところ are the results of  filling a general word to refer to a place, respectively 場所 and ところ, into the placeholders, or gaps, in the following templates.

> 彼が／は＿＿＿にいる。
>
> ＿＿＿で彼女と初めて会った。

You don’t use 指示詞 with those words because 彼がいる and 彼女と初めて会った modify them instead. The English sentence “He is at/in the place” might sound incomplete without context but “the place he is at/in” would be enough to specify what place it is. It is the result of filling in a general word “place” in the gap in the following template.

> He is at/in ______.

English requires a definite article here but you don’t say “that place …” just because “He is at/in that place” sounds more complete than “He is at/in the place” as a standalone sentence. It is the same in Japanese except, of course, there is no equivalent to the definite article and particles like に and で are dropped.

The presence of 指示詞 only makes a difference in whether the relative clause is restrictive (制限的) or non-restrictive (非制限的).

外の関係 refers to a case where the modified noun doesn’t fit in any placeholder, or gap, in the original statement from which the noun phrase is created. For example, the original statement for 魚を焼く匂い would be 魚を焼く. There is no place for 匂い. If you need to create a placeholder to put 匂い into, the template would become something like this.

> ＿＿＿を出して魚を焼く。

This is not considered 内の関係 because the placeholder requires more explanation than a simple case particle like に or で.

Comment: Just to make sure my takeaway from your answer gets it right: 1. 彼が場所にいる and ところで彼女と初めて会った are impossible/ungrammatical, aren't they? 2. With that, does it mean that although 彼がいる場所 can't really be rephrased in such a way that 被修飾名詞 moves to a different position with a 格助詞 to form a natural clause, they are still 内の関係, because as long as there is 格関係 it's 内の関係? 3. Why you say "You don’t use 指示詞 with those words" do you mean with those clauses'd be ungrammatical with 指示詞? Or 指示詞 is not needed? I understand why they unnecessary.  彼がいるその場 appears attested: 彼がいるその場だけ、まるでタイムスリップしたように錯覚させます

Comment: @EddieKal - 1&2. Correct. 彼が場所にいる and ところで彼女と初めて会った don’t have to be grammatical for 彼がいる場所 and 彼女と初めて会ったところ to be grammatical. 3. I meant you don’t use 指示詞 when you want 彼がいる and 彼女と初めて会った to specify what 場所 or ところ you are talking about. You can say 彼がいるその場所 or 彼女と初めて会ったそのところ, of course, but in those sentence その already specifies what 場所 or ところ you refer to. 彼がいる and 彼女と初めて会った add explanation working non-restrictively on その場所 and そのところ. It is like saying “**that** place(, ) where he is” or “**that** place(, ) where I met her for the first time.”

Comment: @EddieKal - The problem with 彼が場所にいる and ところで彼女と初めて会った is a semantic one. Those words are simply too general. その comes in to solve this problem. It doesn't affect 内外関係.

Comment: Oh I see. The impression I got from the canonical answer on relative clauses was case-gapped relative clauses can always be rephrased with the addition of a case particle. That's why I thought since 彼が場所にいる and ところで彼女と初めて会った didn't seem to work, 彼がいる場所 and 彼女と初めて会ったところ must be 外の関係. But now I see why they are 内の関係 after reading your explanation.